# Background thread updates value, OnPropertyChanged invoke on noneui thread so get error

Tags: c#, winforms

I  update value in background thread, OnPropertyChanged invoked at the background thread, so update ui got error
I can use    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
but Is there a better way to solve this problem?

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", a, "Count");
    }

    AAA a = new AAA();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => { a.Count++; }); //get error
        //a.Count++;   this ok
    }
}

class AAA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int count;
    public int Count
    {
        get => count;
        set
        {
            if (value == count) 
                return;

            count = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: `label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", a, "Count", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); (...) Task.Run(()=> BeginInvoke(new Action(() => a.Count++)));`

Comment: Remove `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`. Never use that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be something like this (not tested):

```cs
private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => { 
        _syncContext.Post(() => {
            a.Count++;
        }); 
    }); //get error
}
```

Comment: Edited, should be better now.